# Difference of fixed points by subgroup action

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

If $G$ is a finite group and $X$ is a finite $G$-set, then we have a class equation which tells us
$$|X|=|X^G|+\sum |G/G_x|$$
where $X^G$ is the set of $G$-fixed points, $G_x$ is the stabilizer of $x\in X$ and the sum is taken over representative elements of classes of non-singleton $G$-orbits.

My question, which arise from a proof in a paper which seems to use precisely this fact, is the following.
If $H\leq G$ is a normal subgroup, are we able to write the cartinality of $X^H\setminus X^G$ as sum of cardinalities of $G/H$ orbits? If this is the case, over what that sum is taken?

I guess the result should descend by comparing the two class equations for $H$ and $G$, but I'm struggling to write that down.

Thanks in advance! Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: $G/H$ does act on $X^H\setminus X^G$, so $X^H\setminus X^G$ is a disjoint union of orbits of $G/H$, none of them trivial.

Comment: Which paper are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group $G/H$ acts on $ X^H\setminus X^G$ without fixed points, and so the equation you cited gives
$$|X^H\setminus X^G| = \sum |(G/H)/(G/H)_x|$$ in this case where the sum is over representative elements of the $G/H$-orbits (which are the same as the $G$-orbits) of $X^H\setminus X^G$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, if I understand correctly it follows that the formula only involves $|G/H|$ on the RHS, since stabilizers are trivial, being the action free. Is that correct?

Comment: Why would you assume the stabilizers to be trivial? For instance take any proper subgroup $K \subseteq G$ containing $H$ properly. Let $G$ act on $X = G/K$, so that the stabilizer of any point is conjugate to $K$. Since $H$ is normal and contained in $K$, we see that $H$ acts trivially, so $X^H = X$ and for the action of $G/H$ on $G/K$ the stabilizers are the conjugates of $K/H$.